# How to make Angular app @HostListener('window:unload', ['$event']) handler to finish all the tasks before exiting?

Tags: angular

I try to make 2 http-requests but they are not really made even though the debug stepping indicates that httpclient.delete is called. the execution never stops in breakpoint inside subscribe.

app.component.ts

```
@HostListener('window:unload', ['$event'])
  unloadHandler() {

    this.tabService.closeMainWindow();
  }
```

tab-manager.service.ts

```
  closeMainWindow(): void {
    if (this.windowId === this.sessionId) {
      this.closeWindows();
      this.logout().subscribe(
        () => this.initCache.emptyCache(),
        err => console.error('Deleting plan session resulted in error', err));
    }
  }


private logout() {
    const ses = this.ngRedux.getState().planning.planSession;
    if (ses !== null) {
      return this.httpClient.delete<IPlanSession>(`${this.url}/${ses.id}`).pipe(
        concatMap(() => this.httpClient.post('api/v1/auth/logout', null).pipe(
          tap(() => this.tokenService.logout()))));
    }
    return this.httoClient.post('api/v1/auth/logout', null).pipe(
      tap(() => this.tokenService.logout()));
  }
```

EDIT: Here is [a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36379155/wait-for-promises-in-onbeforeunload) with same problem. However it's old for angular5 and there's no real solution.

Comment: did you mean api inside the `logout` function is not being called ?

Comment: actually not quite sure what is called. Network-tab in browser does not show anything when I debug step by step and next time the plan session is not deleted and logout not made in backend.

Comment: the stepping indicates that both delete and post are called but not really the tokenService.logOut breakpoint is never stopped at.

Comment: but the explanation could be that the unload handler exits and the asynchronic http requests are just not made.

Comment: so the `tokenservice.logout()` is not being called is it correct?

Comment: yes, that is correct and it does not stop at breakpoint inside subscribe.

Answer (score 0):

you can try like this

```
private logout() {
return new Promise(resolve => {
 const ses = this.ngRedux.getState().planning.planSession;
    if (ses !== null) {
      return this.httpClient.delete<IPlanSession>(`${this.url}/${ses.id}`).pipe(
        concatMap(() => this.httpClient.post('api/v1/auth/logout', null).pipe().subscribe(response => {
this.tokenService.logout()
});
    }
    return this.httoClient.post('api/v1/auth/logout', null).pipe().subscribe(response => {
this.tokenService.logout();
resolve(true);
});
});
  }
```

Comment: thanks! i can try that but why this would be any different? this is basically same thing.

Comment: the `tap` operator and it is used for side effects inside a stream. So this operator can be used to do something inside a stream and returning the same observable as it was used on. It runs a method to emit a plain isolated side effect.

Comment: true, this didn't have tap! i try this and  let u know. i just checked fast that u just moved subscribe from closeMainWindow to logout.

Comment: `closeMainWindow` remain as it is. means that function is also contain the `subscribe`

Comment: now i had time to chek this out. this does not make a lot of sense. now it returns subscription and not observable

Comment: @charm now API inside the logout is called or not?

Comment: this does not build, method returns Subsription. that cannot be subscribed.

Comment: Got your point!, I just edit my answer can you check and let me know if it is working or not

Comment: see my edited question. the problem async stuff is not guaranteed to be finished. so your answer ufortunately makes no difference.